# How to create jasper design proggamatticaly at run time

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a table and I want to create a interface where I can decide what columns I want in my report . Please suggest how we can create the design at runtime .

Also how to add images to jasper report . 
Please share any link / document / sample code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370890/is-it-possible-to-generate-reports-dynamically-using-jasper-reports-without-gene or http://dynamicjasper.com/